# How to create time schedule on GitHub

Tags: github, markdown

I found [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50457) with time schedule. It looks like it's written in markdown, however, I'm not sure about the syntax for it.

Does anyone know how to make it? This is the markup that is used:

```
gantt
    dateFormat  YYYY-MM-DD
    TypeScript 4.8 Stabilization Period : 2022-08-05, 2022-08-25
    TypeScript 4.9 Beta Development : 2022-08-05, 2022-09-16
    TypeScript 4.9 RC Development : 2022-09-16, 2022-10-28
    TypeScript 4.9 Stabilization Period : 2022-10-28, 2022-11-15
todayMarker stroke-width:5px,stroke:#0f0,opacity:0.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub's official [Advanced Markdown Documentation on Diagrams](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/creating-diagrams) points you to the right location:
**[Mermaid diagrams/Gantt](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/gantt)**

There is also plenty of literature (theoretical and practical) surrounding [Gantt charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart) and how to use them for project management.